# How to drop down a list of countries automatically with cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, formhelper

Hello i'm a biginner in cakephp and i'm trying to create a simple app of registration and authentication 
In the registration form i wanna the country input lists all countries automatically. i've done researches but i hadn't something helpful 
Can anybody help me and thanks in advance

Comment: kindly refer to the guide to know more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 

What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly cake-specific, or a new issue.  A little googling goes a long way, and without even leaving this site you have a ton of useful pointers here [Is there a centralized list of country names that can be used for web drop down boxes (and validation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332685/is-there-a-centralized-list-of-country-names-that-can-be-used-for-web-drop-down)